# Continuation of a vector field on projective space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

In the book of V.I. Arnold "Ordinary differential equations" there is a lemma which states that any vector field $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be uniquely continued to a smooth vector field $\overline{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}P^n$. As an example author gives vector field
$$\dot{x} = Ax,$$
where x is some linear operator. Author gives a constructive way of continuation: 
we have 
$$\dot{x}^i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{j}.$$
Also we have transition map between affine part of $\mathbb{R}P^n = \mathbb{R}^n$ and "infinite part" which is given by
$$y_1 = x_1^{-1}; y_j = x_j x_1^{-1}, x_1 \neq 0$$
therefore 
$$\dot{y}_1 = -y_1(a_{11} + \sum_{j=2}^{n} a_{1j}y_j) \\
  \dot{y}_i = a_{i1} + \sum_{j=2}^{n} a_{1j}y_j -y_1(a_{11} + \sum_{j=2}^{n} a_{1j}y_j),$$
so we can define it on $y_1 = 0$:
$$\dot{y}_1\vert_{y_1 = 0} = 0 \\
  \dot{y}_i\vert_{y_1 = 0} = a_{i1} + \sum_{j=2}^{n} a_{1j}y_j.$$ But when i tred it on very simple example
$$\dot{x} = x^3, x \in \mathbb{R}$$ it didn't work because i got $y_1$ in denominator of right hand side. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example $n=1$ and the vector field is defined by $x' = x^3$. The meaning of this is that $x$ is a coordinate chart and in homogeneous coordinates you have $[x:1]$. To extend your vector field to the whole $\mathbb{R}P^1$ you take the other chart $y$ i.e. $[1:y]$, and perform the change of coordinates $x = \frac{1}{y}$. Then your vector field in the coordinate $y$ is $y' = - \frac{1}{y}$. So as far as I see your vector field can not be extended to the whole $\mathbb{R}P^1$ hence you are not doing something wrong.